# ParseObject subclass not retrieving lists

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am using Parse with Unity and I have subclassed the objects I am saving. The object I am retrieving ne has a few lists, including some that are just int arrays. Currently I can retreive the object, but the lists are null. Even when using `query.include("columnid")`

Example code

```
// In this code MPGameState contains an array of pointers to the Player Object
// Deck is an array of integers
// both are null in the callback
public void Init (string gameID) {
    ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<MPPlayer> ();
    ParseObject.RegisterSubclass<MPGameState> ();

    var query = new ParseQuery<MPGameState> ()
        .WhereEqualTo ("objectId", gameID);

    query.Include ("Players");
    query.Include ("Deck");

    query.FirstAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
        gameState = (MPGameState) t.Result;

        Debug.LogFormat("Players {0} | Deck {1}", gamestate.Players, gameState.Deck);
    });
}
```

What do I need to do to get this code to return the list values for my int arrays and pointer arrays?

Comment: Still not working. Tried a number of different ways of retrieving objects, but still puzzled.

Comment: Turns out its a bug in parse https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/139540766384357/?search_id